# Exclude/mask sensitive fields from StructuredArguments in logback

Tags: logging, logstash, logback

Currently i am logging using logback the request details as below

```
logger.info("Request Data", kv(LoggingConstants.PRINCIPAL, request.getUserPrincipal());
```

for which the generated log is below

```
{
    "principal": {
        "authorities": [],
        "details": {
            "remoteAddress": "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
            **"sessionId": "489JW9JW9JW0W4884494JF8W0KSD0WEWE0",
            "tokenValue": "aasweiji2niifa903jfe9j0wkw9jawef-2jfweafpas0fw3fawejf0pwefj[0kfpwejf9pjfpawofp9wfjpwafjapfi]0-fkmawepofcmawe9fj wefk",**
            "tokenType": "Bearer",
            "decodedDetails": null
        },
        "authenticated": true,
        "userAuthentication": {
            "authorities": [],
            "details": null,
            "authenticated": true,
            "credentials": "",
            "name": "admin",
            "principal": "admin"
        },
        "oauth2Request": {
            "clientId": null,
            "scope": [],
            "requestParameters": {
                "client_id": null
            },
            "resourceIds": [
                "ABC"
            ],
            "authorities": [],
            "approved": true,
            "refresh": false,
            "redirectUri": null,
            "responseTypes": [],
            "extensions": {},
            "grantType": null,
            "refreshTokenRequest": null
        },
        "credentials": "",
        "clientOnly": false,
        "principal": "admin",
        "name": "admin"
    }
}
```

we are using below encoder

```
<encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
```

How can i exclude or mask the sensitive data like tokenValue , sessionId from the log ?

Comment: Where do you want to remove? Before sending to logstash or in the logstash pipeline? It is very simple to remove in the logstash pipeline, just need to parse the json message and use the remove_field option from the mutate filter.

Comment: I want to remove before sending to log itself (we are using consoleappender)

Comment: [Aleksander Parchomenko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14215089) wrote an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66024777) saying "Maybe you should look at this:https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder#masking"